# For invertible matrix $B$, does always apply $\operatorname{rank}(AC)=\operatorname{rank}(ABB^{\dagger}C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For invertible complex matrix $B$, for $B^{\dagger}$ the Hermitian conjugate, does for all compatible complex matrices $A,C$ necessarily apply $\operatorname{rank}(AC)=\operatorname{rank}(ABB^{\dagger}C)$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
;C=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
;B=
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
1 & -i\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$B^*=\begin{pmatrix}
-i & 1 \\
0 & i \\
\end{pmatrix}
;AC=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
;ABB^*C=
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

It is clear, that $rank(B)=2$ thus $B$ is invertible, but $0 = rank(AC) \ne rank(ABB^*C) = 1$, so we constructed a counterexample.